# Asp.net Mvc cant read request path after #

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

I want to add 301 routing on my website (created by Asp.net Mvc 4)

i read the url from Application_BeginRequest Callback in global.asax

but when there is a request like below , i cant read that all

http://localhost:443/MyPath/MySomeHtml.html#labels=123,1234

i need this all url because there is some different labels on same file request

like :

~/MyPath/MySomeHtml.html#labels=123,1234~

~/MyPath/MySomeHtml.html#labels=brands,122,123

~/MyPath/MySomeHtml.html#labels=tag,224

how can i reach all the url ?

thanks in advice.

Comment: The `#` is a fragment identifier and anything after it is not sent to the controller

Comment: this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values has an array of values for the current route, such as "action" "any"

Comment: ok then , we try to handle this on javascript side , thanks for all advices

Answer (score 0):

You can only apply a 301/302 action to the URL itself, and not the label.

The `#` part of the URL is only parsed by the browser as far as I am aware.